# phpmailer returning response null in slim

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using slim framework to create api's for android app.In CreateUser api, i am sending mail to user using phpmailer.Phpmailer is sending the mails to user perfectly but my array response is returning null array response due to it.When i remove the code of  phpmailer response is correct and when i add it ,it generates null reponse.

Here is my code in Dbhandler.php:

```
   $app->post('/requestPreview', function() use ($app) {
        verifyRequiredParams(array('fname', 'lname', 'email','event_code','app_version'));
        global $user_id;
        $response = array();

        $fname = urldecode($app->request->post('fname'));
        $lname = urldecode($app->request->post('lname'));
        $email =  urldecode($app->request->post('email'));
        $event_code =  urldecode($app->request->post('event_code'));
        $app_version =  urldecode($app->request->post('app_version'));
        $db = new DbHandler();
        //$db->sendmail($email);
        $res = $db->signup($fname, $lname, $email,$event_code,$app_version);

        if ($res['status']=="one") {
            //$password=$res['password'];
            $response["event_code"] = $event_code;
            $response["email"] = $email;
            $response["fname"] =$fname;
            $response["lname"] = $lname;
            $response["CreateUser"] = true;
                       $mail = new PHPMailer();  
                           $mail->IsSMTP();
                           $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

                           $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
                           $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                           $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

                           $mail->Username = "abc.abc@gmail.com";
                           $mail->Password = "***********";
                           $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                           $mail->Port = 587;

                           $mail->From     = "abc.abc@gmail.com";
                           $mail->AddAddress($email);
                           $mail->isHTML(true); 
                           $mail->Subject  = "Welcome to www.abc.com .Your Account has been created and your password is:";
                           $mail->Body     = "Welcome to www.abc.com .Your Account has been created and your password is:";

                          $mail->send();    



        } else if ($res['status']=="two"){


            $response["error"] ="already_in_system";
            $response["fname"] = null;
            $response["lname"] = null;



        }
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
      });
```

Comment: I hope that's not your real password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to [latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and base your code on [an up to date example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), then read [the troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). It's very likely you're running into Google auth issues.

Your PHPMailer code never touches `$response`, suggesting it may be exiting prematurely due to an error, so trace what's happening in your function.

Comment: I have updated  my PHPMailer.But still if i add the phpmailer code, $response is wrong ,as well as the mail is sent and when i remove the code response is correct. I think PHPMailer is not working correctly @synchro

Comment: previously i was including class.phpmailer.php.But now i am including phpmailerAutoload.php and changed the configuration as you said but still the problem exists.

Comment: Did you actually do what the guide says and enable debug output? If so, post what it said in your question.

Comment: I have edited my code.Now i have placed the phpmailer code where the api response is printed and the result is that it always goes to else part and if i put phpmailer code in else part then the response from if condition is always generated

Comment: If i donot write the phpmailer code in any of the condition then my signup works perfectly

Comment: That makes no sense. Step through the code with a debugger so you can see what it's really doing.

Comment: Just put echo statements showing where it has got to in the code. PHPMailer will be generating debug output, so see where that is going. Ideally, use an IDE like NetBeans or PHPStorm to step through the code. It doesn't help that you're not checking any return values.

Comment: Please answer this question .Its very urgent for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623754/create-video-thumbnail-in-slim

Comment: $mail->send function fires the api again @synchro.Please help

Comment: I don't think this is anything to do with PHPMailer. PHPMailer never calls your API. It's very likely that your browser is submitting twice - this is often done by browser plugins. I've already told you how to debug it, so you need to get on with doing that; nobody can do it for you.

Comment: but when i donot use php mailer api fires only once

Comment: I adopted the alternative way of fetching response at android end i.e using  Http urlconnection(doing in background) and everything is working correctly.