# Phpmailer call slim api twice

Tags: php, phpmailer, slim

I am using Slim framework for creating my api. I am sending email using phpmailer. The mail is sending correctly. But my problem is that `$mail->send()` is firing my api twice due to which my response is wrong. Please tell me why `$mail->send()` is calling my api again in slim and how can I resolve it. Here is my code

```php
$app->post('/requestPreview', function () use ($app) {
    //  $file = fopen('testphpmailer.txt',"w");
    verifyRequiredParams(array('fname', 'lname', 'email', 'event_code', 'app_version'));
    global $user_id, $condition;

    $response = array();

    $fname = $app->request->post('fname');
    $lname = $app->request->post('lname');
    $email = $app->request->post('email');
    $event_code = $app->request->post('event_code');
    $app_version = $app->request->post('app_version');
    //echo fwrite($file,"incoming vaiables: Firstname=".$fname);
    //echo fwrite($file,"incoming vaiables: Lastname=".$lname);
    //echo fwrite($file,"incoming vaiables: Email=".$email);
    //echo fwrite($file,"incoming vaiables: event_code=".$event_code);
    //echo fwrite($file,"incoming vaiables: app_version=".$app_version);

    $db = new DbHandler();
    //$db->sendmail($email);
    $res = $db->signup($fname, $lname, $email, $event_code, $app_version);

    //echo fwrite($file,"Result".$res['status']);
    if ($res['status'] == "one") {
        //echo fwrite($file,"Inside If".$res['status']);

        $password = $res['password'];

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username = "abc@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "*******";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->From = "abc@gmail.com";
        $mail->AddAddress("abc@gmail.com");
        $mail->Subject = "Welcome to www.abc.com .Your Account has been created and your password is:";
        $mail->Body = "Welcome to www.abc.com .Your Account has been created and your password is:";
        $mail->Send(); /*When this line runs then it it send the gmail and my api is called  and below mentioned response is never executed*/

        $response["event_code"] = $event_code;
        $response["email"] = $email;
        $response["fname"] = $fname;
        $response["lname"] = $lname;
        $response["CreateUser"] = false;
        echoRespnse(200, $response);

    } else {
        // echo fwrite($file,"Inside else = ".$res['status']);

        $response["error"] = "already in system";
        $response["fname"] = "null";
        $response["lname"] = "null";
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    }
    //echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
    //fclose($file);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpmailer returning response null in slim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605117/phpmailer-returning-response-null-in-slim)

Comment: Asking the same question again isn't going to help.

Comment: I have debugged my code

Comment: Can you please help me now

Comment: $mail->send() call my api again due to which reasponse =already in systems is generated.Actually it is very urgent for me thats why i posted with new changes

Comment: `$mail->send` **never** calls your API. You need to use basic debugging techniques - echo something, log something - as I told you the last time you asked this same question.

Comment: $mail->send() doesnot give any error i have checked it using $mail->ErrorInfo and it does not go in catch block also and email is sent successfuly

Comment: As I said, it is is not phpmailer doing this. It does not call your APIs **at all**. I suspect logging will show you receiving multiple requests.

Comment: Ok Synchro. BDW  can you please tell me why phpmailer is sending to filed empty in mail I ahve added AddReplyto field but to is still empty

Comment: The `to` address has nothing to do with `addReplyTo`. If you're finding `to` is empty, try checking the return value from `addAddress`.

Comment: Removing $mail->SingleTo solved the problem of empty to field in mail .

Comment: And the main problem i asked was also resolved. Actually i was fetching the response from json .But i fetched the response from Http url connection using asynchronous task and the my phpmailer problem was also resolved and everything is working fine .Thanks @Synchro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was fetching the response from json. But when I fetched the response from Http urlconnection using asynchronous task and the my phpmailer problem was also resolved and everything is working fine now.

Comment: I am geeting out of memory error in imageloader when i try to click on thumbnail and view image.when i see the 10th image i get oom Please anyone help.How to resolve it??